# Contradictory definitions of Open And Closed set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

According to Erwin Kreyszig, The Open and closed set are defined as

> A subset $M$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be *open* if it contains a ball about each of its points. A  subset $K$ of $X$ is said to be closed if its complement (in $X$) is open, that is, $K^C=X-K$ is open.

According to Ravi P. Agrawal in his An Introduction to Complex Analysis

> A set $S$ is said to be *closed* if it contains all of its boundary points; i.e., $\partial S \subseteq S. $. It follows that $S$ is open if and only if its complement $\mathbf{C}-S$ is closed. The sets $\mathbf{C}$ and $\emptyset$ are both open and closed.

---

I found a contradictory example. Suppose $X=(1,5)$ ($X$ is usual metric space)  and $K=(1,2]\cup [4,5)$.

From the second definition, it's clear that $K$ is not a closed set.

From the first,

$$K^C=X-K=(2,4)$$
which is open, so $K$ must be closed follows from the first definition.

But the two definitions seem to be contradicting each other. Please, Point out flaws in my thinking.

---

As an additional doubt. In the second definition, Will the  statement

> $S$ is open if and only if its complement $\mathbf{C}-S$ is closed.

is follow independent of

> The sets $\mathbf{C}$ and $\emptyset$ are both open and closed.

?

Comment: Actually, the definition does say that $K$ is closed... where is your contradiction?

Comment: $K$ is closed, since it contains all of its boundary points (which are $2,4$)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$K$ does contain all its boundary points because $\partial K = \{2, 4\}$.

You seem to erroneously believe that $1$ and $5$ are boundary points. But the boundary of $K$ must be a subset of $X$. Since neither $1$ nor $5$ is in $X$, $K$ is a closed subset of $X$.

To be more precise, the boundary of $K$ is defined as $\{x \in X | x$ is a limit point of $K$ and $x$ is a limit point of $X \setminus K\}$. The very definition of the boundary of $K$ precludes us from saying that $1 \in \partial K$.

Comment: Can you answer the additional doubt too that I have pointed out?

Comment: @YoungKindaichi I'm not exactly sure what your additional doubt is. But it is certainly true that the definition of a closed set as a set with an empty complement will ensure that both the empty set and the whole space are closed, because it follows from the definition of a metric space that their complements (which are the empty set and the whole space) are open.